# How to get related questions' IDs of a certain question in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, data-explorer, related-questions

I am trying to get the related questions' IDs of a question.

So let say the question ID I am seeing now is "1" and I want the ID numbers of all the *related* questions on the sidebar.

Answer (score 4):

This information is not available in SEDE (unlike the Linked Questions which are stored in the `PostLinks` table).

Fortunately, we have jQuery. Open the Developer Tools of your browser, go to the Console and enter the following JavaScript:

```
$(".sidebar-related").find("a.question-hyperlink").each(function() {
    console.log(/\/questions\/(\d+)\//.exec($(this).attr("href"))[1]);
});
```

For this question, it returns the following IDs:

> 7046
>   7931
>   20473
>   29508
>   60104
>   87198
>   170636
>   203931
>   258046
>   258943

Comment: +1, Nice trick using jQuery.

Comment: @Arulkumar [It's really great and does all things.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Stack API for that.

The endpoint [`/questions/{ids}/related`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-questions) returns the related question list.

For this question you would use the following link:

> [`questions/293458/related?order=desc&sort=activity&site=meta&filter=!w-1xWerkm*L5vaQIU-`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=293458&filter=!w-1xWerkm*L5vaQIU-&site=meta&run=true)

which returns, roughly, this:

```js
{
    "items" : [{
            "last_activity_date" : 1487868137,
            "question_id" : 7931,
            "link" : "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites",
            "title" : "FAQ for Stack Exchange sites"
        }, {
            "last_activity_date" : 1480040779,
            "question_id" : 7046,
            "link" : "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions",
            "title" : "Getting attention for unanswered questions?"
        }
      // left out some results
    ]
}
```

I leave it to the reader to parse that into a format for your purpose.